# How to set up Mixpanel / Swift SDK with pre-processor flag MIXPANEL_RANDOM_DISTINCT_ID=1

Tags: ios, swift, sdk, mixpanel

I need to set up Mixpanel / Swift SDK with pre-processor flag MIXPANEL_RANDOM_DISTINCT_ID=1

I've read instruction from official Mixpanel documentation, but I don't understand how set up that.

---

[Mixpanel documentation](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/swift#call-reset-on-logout)

---

**Instruction from documentation**

Call Reset on Logout
Reset generates a new random distinct_id and clears super properties. Call reset to clear data attributed to a user when that user logs out. This allows you to handle multiple users on a single device. For more information about maintaining user identity, see the Identity Management: Best Practices article.

Generate a non-IFA distinct_id by setting the MIXPANEL_RANDOM_DISTINCT_ID pre-processor flag and calling reset on logout. Calling reset will only clear the existing distinct_id from the cookie (browser) or local storage (mobile). You can set the MIXPANEL_RANDOM_DISTINCT_ID=1 pre-processor flag in your Active Compilation Conditions on the Mixpanel framework target.

After you call reset, Mixpanel generates a new distinct_id. If the MIXPANEL_RANDOM_DISTINCT_ID=1 preprocessor flag is set, the SDK will generate a non-IFA random persistent UUI, to use as the distinct_id. The SDK will ensure that all distinct_ids will not be the IFA, and will use the UUID. Setting the MIXPANEL_RANDOM_DISTINCT_ID=1 preprocessor flag and calling reset ensures that multiple users on the same device are not assigned the same alias.

---

Answer (score 0):

I've found the right solution.

[mixpanel-swift / issue #381](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-swift/issues/381#issuecomment-646947644)

---

**Put this in your Podfile if you are experiencing user profiles merged together after sign out:**

```
 post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          if target.name == 'Mixpanel-swift'
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] = '$(inherited) -D COCOAPODS -D DECIDE -D MIXPANEL_RANDOM_DISTINCT_ID'
              end
          end
      end
  end
```

And don't forget... `Command-Option-Shift-K` to make your problems go away!

---